# Why is the Workflow Designer so extremely slow when editing build process templates?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process, workflow-foundation-4

There's not much more to add really than the above question.

I have a fairly simple build process template, which has hardly deviated from the default one.

I have two custom activities, which by recommendation live in a separate assembly within the same solution.

However....

Opening the template takes about two minutes.

Changing properties on an activity in the workflow, reordering activities in the workflow, adding activities to the workflow, all take between 30-60 seconds.

It's completely unusable at the moment and I'm beginning to regret moving from Cruise Control to TFS for build management :(

Does anyone else experience this or know a decent workaround? Is it better to simply edit the XAML text by hand?

Thanks

Comment: Crappy machine? No memory?  Could be lots of things.  Have you tried VS in /safemode yet?

Comment: I have 8gb of RAM and 3gHz quad core, don't think it's the machine to be honest.  I haven't tried /safemode, no, I will give it a shot. Also this problem seems to be omnipresent in our organisation - other teams with other build projects have the same issues and there is no commonality (other than the .NET and TFS libraries) between these projects. No network shares are being used.

Comment: Is *any* workflow editing slow?  Or is it just the build definitions (which can be huuuuge)?  Also, vidya drivers updated?  Lots of WPF going on in the design surface.

Comment: I logged a lot of VS2010 WF designer questions to Microsoft Forum. But they never reply any useful information. ALl we can do is just wait for the next patch =.='

Comment: visual studio 2017 doesn't have a workflow designer. how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

We just upgraded from TFS 2008 to 2010 and I have the very same experience as Steve opening the unedited DefaultTemplate.xaml file. VS 2010 even gets into not responding state. Hardware: 3GHz Dual Core, 4GB RAM.

It is not just slow but unusable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can edit a build definition. (or any workflow definition)
First, you can start from root and start expanding details. All levels are shown in a single view and this approach is extremely slow. More detail items you expand, more slow it gets.

Instead, you can keep the build workflow collapsed and drill into detail items by double clicking on title which opens detail items in separate views and does not introduce any performance problems.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to have any impact on the real issues I face in terms of performance - namely opening the xaml file in the designer, and editing the properties of the various activities.  They remain the same regardless of whether the whole workflow is open or collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? VS 2010 is quite slow in general on Windows XP, I believe that this is due to it being built using WPF. There is a [KB](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=cd55456d-9703-42a0-b982-8a8a89ca0aa3&displaylang=en) which is meant to speed up VS2010 in Windows XP. I've used it, but to be honest I didn't notice much difference. That could be down to the poor hardware I'm forced to use though!

Answer (score 0):

Steve I agree with you. I've been using workflows for build definitions for a while and VS2010 loads them extremely slow. Furthermore, when I make any modification or save the file, it takes over 15 seconds to modify and over 40 to save and I'm running them in a pretty good machine. It would be interesting to know whether this issue has been solved in VS2012 or not. Anyone has tested it?

--

**UPDATE [01/02/2013]:**

**All this issues have been sorted out with the new versión of [Microsoft Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng)**

Build process workflow templates and Visual Studio 2010 was an absolutely nightmare. As I said before it takes ages to modify anything and even tough we improved considerably our machines we did not get good results. The upgrade from VS2010 to VS2012 in build workflow templates is bit problematic, the template contains versioned namespaces which must be cleaned up in order to be used with VS2010. For further information about migrating issues visit [Jason Prickett's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/07/17/tfs-2012-cleaning-up-workflow-xaml-files-aka-removing-versioned-namespaces.aspx).

Comment: For me, the issue was solved by moving to an alternative build solution. It allows me to make modifications to the build process quickly and focus on more important things. Sad that TFS had to be ditched for such a silly reason really...

Comment: @Steve I tried that several times with no results. Finally, after a deep research I found the solution mentioned above.